# Convert a media file to h.264 encoding using melt on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, h.264, mlt

I am working on a small command line video editing tool. I have created almost everything but I am stuck at encoding of result file in to H.264.
I installed melt from debian repository. encoding wasn't working so i tried building melt on my own. but it showing some error while disabling qimage and i can't figure it out.

Following is an example command:

```
melt Wildlife.wmv -consumer avformat:test.mp4 vcodec=libx264
```

Tt starts processing but shows:

> [consumer avformat] video codec libx264 unrecognised - ignoring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by removing melt and ffmpeg installed from the repository and compiled it manually. it fixed the issue and also a latest version with some bug fixes and new features.
on repository it 0.0.7 but if complied manually it is at 0.8.9 right now.

here is the instructions to compile melt.
[melt script](http://www.mltframework.org/bin/view/MLT/BuildScripts)

use the melted section to only compile command line video editor use any other to install any gui video editors like OpenShot or kdenlive

Answer (score 0):

You need to install libx264 on your system. Do you have that?

Comment: Yes, i have installed x264 and ffmpeg also, if i try encoding a media file using ffmpeg to h.264 it works just fine.

Comment: Then while building melt do you have to explicitly enable libx264?